# Proof that $x^n=y$ with accumulation point

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

given a sequence $(y_n)$ with $y_n \ge 0$ for all integers $n$ and $(x_n)=\sqrt[N]{y_n} $ with a constant value $N$ out of the natural numbers.

I want prove that $x^N=y$.

I know that $(y_n)$ is limited because $(y_n)$ converges and thus it follows by definition. From that I already concluded that $(x_n)$ is limited too and using Bolzano-Weierstraß Theorem $(x_n)$ has at least one accumulation point which is called $x$.
I thought that I can solve this problem by showing that $(x_n)$ converges to $\sqrt[N]{y}$ and from that one can conclude that $x^N=y$.
But I am stuck at this point. If it would be just the square root of $y$ it would be easy to show by definition of convergent sequences but here we have the Nth root for a given N.

Can someone give me a hint? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can go with $N$th root the same way as with square roots:

$$x - x_n = \sqrt[N]{y} - \sqrt[N]{y_n} = \frac{y - y_n}{\sqrt[N]{y}^{N - 1} + \sqrt[N]{y}^{N - 2}\sqrt[N]{y_n} + \ldots + \sqrt[N]{y_n}^{N - 1}}$$

Numerator converges to $0$ and, is $y \neq 0$, denominator is separated from $0$ (as it's at least $\sqrt[N]{y}^{N - 1}$), so fraction converges to $0$.

If $y = 0$, we should use definition of limit: choose $\epsilon$, find $n_0$ s.t. $y_n < \epsilon^N$ if $n > n_0$, and take the same $n_0$ for $x_n$: if $n > n_0$ then $x_n = \sqrt[N]{y_n} < \sqrt[N]{\epsilon^N} = \epsilon$.

Alternatively, it's not hard to show that $x \to x^N$ is continuous and bijective on any segment that doesn't include $0$, so inverse of it, $x \to \sqrt[N]{x}$ is continuous too (and we still need to separately show continuity in $0$ for even $N$).